# Recursively patten js

Tags: javascript, regex, web

I want to check a recursively text that verufy three rules.

1º:  All the string should be a sequence of numbers between 0-31 + a dot .

Example: 1.23.5.12

2º: The string can't begin or end with a dot.
Like this.
 .1.23.5.12.

3º You can write a max of 51 digits (following the previous rules)

I tried to make a pattern to my js function. But this dont work.

This is my function:

```
  var str = document.getElementById("numero").value;
        var patt1 = /^[0-9]+\./g;
        var result = str.match(patt1);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

What is wrong in the pattern?

Comment: It doesn't restrict the numbers to the expected range `0-31`, and the content of `numero` has to end with a dot

Comment: So, if I change the pattern to this "/^[0-31]+\./g;", it should work? I'm, beginning to use patterns , and this is like a little chaos for me haha

Comment: No, this won't work either: https://regex101.com/r/JFXY5h/1/

Comment: It's solved. Thanks for your answer Andreas :)

Comment: Another variant: [`^(?!(?:\d\.?){52})(?:(?:[12]?\d|3[01])\.?\b)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/EtM45E/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!(?:\D*\d){52})(?:[12]?\d|3[01])(?:\.(?:[12]?\d|3[01]))*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIRzlH/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\D*\d){52})` - fail if there are 52 or more digits separated with any 0+ non-digits
- `(?:[12]?\d|3[01])` - `1` or `2` (optional) followed with any single digit or `3` followed with `0` or `1` (`0` - `31`)
- `(?:\.(?:[12]?\d|3[01]))*` - zero or more consecutive repetitions of

  - `\.` - dot
  - `(?:[12]?\d|3[01])` - see above (`0` - `31`)
- `$` - end of string.

Use it with `test`:

```
if (/^(?!(?:\D*\d){52})(?:[12]?\d|3[01])(?:\.(?:[12]?\d|3[01]))*$/.test(str)) {
    // Valid!
}
```

Test:

```js
var rx = /^(?!(?:\D*\d){52})(?:[12]?\d|3[01])(?:\.(?:[12]?\d|3[01]))*$/;
var strs = [".12", "123", "1.23.5.12", "12345678"];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the pattern accepts values like ".12"  (Begin with dot ) , "123" (bigger than 31)

Comment: @Abraham See the code snippet with tests. Please implement the regex this way to avoid issues, that is, do not use `g` modifier, use `RegExp#test`.

Comment: Okey, I dont saw the test. Sorry, Let me try it :)

Comment: It works Wiktor, thanks you again. This is the second day that you help me with the patterns :)

Answer (score 2):

The regex `^[0-9]+\.` matches from the start of the string `^` one or more digits `[0-9]+` followed by a dot `\.`

You might use:

[`^(?!(\.?\d){52})(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/tfRRxt/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `(?!(\.?\d){52})` Negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not 52 times an optional dot followed by one or more digits
- `(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` Match a number 0 - 31
- `(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))+` Repeat in a group matching a dot followed by a number 0 - 31 and repleat that one or more times so that a single digit wihtout a dot does not match
- `$` Assert the end of the string

```js
const strings = [
  '1.23.5.12',
  '1.23.5.12.',
  '.1.23.5.12.',
  '1.23.5.12',
  '1',
  '1.23.5.12.1.23.5.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.2',
  '1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12.1.23.5.12'

];
let pattern = /^(?!(\.?\d){52})(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))+$/;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Comment: I finally use the first answer of the post. But thanks for your help  :)